# Sending index to XMLHttpRequest onLoad() results only using the last index for all onLoad()

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I pass an index value to onLoad(), so when it starts running on the background it will use the index value to index an array. Problem is, from what it looks like, when onLoad() does start to run the index value it refers to is always the last index.

I have tried setting each request (XMLHttpRequest) property to the index it should be using when onLoad() starts.

```
    setXMLOnLoad (request, index, chart) {

        let lenOfEachArray = this.lenOfEachArray;
        const wrapSensorArray = (index) => {return this.getSensorArray(index)};
        const wrapSetSensorArray = (index, data) => {this.setSensorArray(index, data);};

        //request.op = new Number(index);
        request.op = index;
        console.log(request.op); // reports 0 then 1 (fine)

        request.onload = function () {
            let sIndex = request.op; // reports 1 every time! (not fine)
            console.log(sIndex);
        }
    }

    createXMLRequests (chart) {
        this.XMLRequestsArray = new Array(this.getNum()).fill(new XMLHttpRequest());

        this.XMLRequestsArray.forEach((request,index) => {
            this.setXMLOnLoad(request, index, chart);
        });
    }

    sendXMLRequests (link) {
        this.XMLRequestsArray.forEach((request, index) => {

            let id = index + 1;
            let finalLink = link.concat(`${id}`);

            request.open("GET", finalLink);
            request.send();            
        });
    }
```

Expecting `request.op` to return its correct index value in onLoad() that was pre-assigned.

Comment: So, setting async to false gets all onLoad() to run and setting property for request after it is open gives the correct index value when onLoad() runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer

The problem is that `fill(new XMLHttpRequest())` actually only creates one XMLHttpRequest instance that gets overwritten, which cancels previous http calls. You can see this when you open the network tab in the inspector: only one Request comes through, the others get canceled.

This small snippet sends 4 http requests, so what you want is still possible, hopefully you can adjust your code with this!

```
function createXMLRequests () {
  let XMLRequestsArray = [new XMLHttpRequest(), new XMLHttpRequest(), new XMLHttpRequest()]

  XMLRequestsArray.forEach((request,index) => {  
    request.onload = function () {
      console.log("request fulfilled");
      console.log(index)  
    }
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost/test.php");
    request.send();  

  });
}


createXMLRequests()
```

Comment: It looks like one of my onLoad()  isn't being called, probably the first one

Comment: I found that your httpRequests get canceled by the browser, that's why you only get 1 result. In this snippet you get all results. And perhaps it's possible to put everything in one `forEach` loop for easier readability.

Comment: Got it. I noticed if the XMLRequestsArray is initialized outside the createXMLRequests() function then you still get only the last request to send. Another SO thread says "the request variable must be declared and scoped inside the loop." Not sure why that is that, but it does work for async calls. Thanks!